# sqlalchemy/postgres: parameterizing column names in queries at run time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlalchemy/postgres query that is run like this (example code):

```
start = # a datetime value
end   = # a datetime value
engine = # the definition of an engine
table = Table('table_name', ... etc. ...)
query = select(['*'])
results = engine.connect().execute(query).where(between(table.c.some_column, start, end))
```

This is simple and straightforward. However, it turns out that I want to reuse this code with a different table name and a different column name, both of which are specified as strings in a config file.

So for example, suppose that table "xyz" contains a column called "the_timestamp", and suppose the table "abc" contains a column called "the_time". I associate "xyz" with "the_timestamp" in a config file and associate "abc" with "the_time" in the config file. Then, depending upon which table/column combination is selected from the config file, the `where` clause will use "the_timestamp" if the table is "xyz" and "the_time" if the table is "abc".

Obviously, the table part of this is trivial, because the `Table()` function takes a string as an argument. However, the column name in the `where` clause is not a string, but rather, it's a reference to an sqlalchemy object. I'd like to have the column name in the `where` clause be dynamically set to the column name string from the config file, instead of using a pre-defined object for the name of the column.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this in sqlalchemy. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to dynamically define and access the table and columns. You probably want to use [`table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.table) and [`column`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column) instead of [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) and [`Column`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column) so that you don't need to take care to remove these dynamically created objects from the `MetaData`. So:

```
t = table(table_name, column(col_name1), column(col_name2), ...)
```

To use these dynamically, use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
select([t]).where(getattr(t.c, col_name1) == "foo")
```

Comment: OK, I see. Apparently there is no sqlalchemy-specific way to use a dynamic column name, and so I just use the pythonic `getattr()` function to perform introspection. Thank you.

Comment: @HippoMan The SQLAlchemy way *is* to use `table` and `column`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part. I'm talking about passing `t.c` to `getattr()`. That is pythonic introspection.

Comment: @HippoMan You *could* just do `.where(column(col_name1) == "foo")` but that's less flexible.

Comment: Understood. Thank you again.